# Error in wilcox.test : object 'x' not found

Tags: r

I'm trying to complete a mann-whitney-wilcoxon test in R to compare brood sizes between 2 years. My data read in successfully in 2 columns, labeled x and y for each year, ranked, with unequal sample sizes.  I'm getting the following error and I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
setwd('c:/OSPR NEST 2011 & 2012')
penob1112<-read.csv('compare_penob_11_12.csv',header=TRUE)

wilcox.test(x, y, data=penob1112)
Error in wilcox.test(x, y, data = penob1112) : object 'x' not found
```

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: can you show us the head of the data (`head(penob1112)`)?

Comment: try wilcox.test(penob1112$x, penob1112$y) to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` argument is only taken when the first argument is of class `formula`. You need to explicitly call each object instead:

```
wilcox.test(penob1112$x, penob1112$y)
```

Look at `?wilcox.test` - it has two methods (`default` and `formula`)